# Proof of Ptolemy's Theorem using only trigonometric formulas

Tags: geometry

I'm a high school teacher, working through a trigonometry unit with my class, and I've been giving some extension problems to some of my students. We've worked through the main trigonometric formulas (Pythagoras, SOH, CAH, TOA, sine rule, cosine rule, area of a triangle, and the sine and cosine addition formulas).

We've used those to work out some more interesting formulas, such as:

Heron's formula for the area of a triangle: $A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)} $, and:

Brahmagupta's formula for the area of a cyclic quadrilateral: $A = \sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)} $, where a, b, c, d are side lengths, and s is the semi-perimeter (half the perimeter).

What I would like to do is to work through Ptolemy's theorem: $pq=ac+bd$, where p and q are the diagonals, and a, b, c, d are the sides of a cyclic quadrilateral (with a and c opposite). I have seen many proofs online (most of which are quite elegant), but they all use more than I have taught my class.

I would like to see a proof of Ptolemy's Theorem using **only**

- Pythagoras
- SOH, CAH, TOA
- sine and cosine rules
- sine and cosine addition/subtraction formulas
- Opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral add to 180 degrees

Comment: You can prove it using only similar triangles.  Not even any trig.

Comment: Have you seen Wikipedia's [proof by trigo identites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem#Proofs)? I guess it satisfies what you want.

Comment: @CalvinLin I like the similar triangles proof, but it's not what I've been teaching my students, I want one that doesn't rely on that.

Comment: @ThomasBlok I'm referring to the proof via trigonometric identities. Specifically, we want to show that $ \sin (a+b) + \sin (b+c) = \sin a \sin c + \sin b \sin (a+b+c)$. In fact, you could have them prove the identity first by expanding out the sin summation, then tell them to use (extended) sine rule to derive Ptolemy's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

$AC=p,~~ BD=q$

[image]

Multiply those red circled terms,

$$ac=\frac{\sin x\sin\beta}{\sin(\alpha+x)\sin(\alpha+\beta)}\cdot pq$$

Multiply those blue circled terms,

$$bd=\frac{\sin \alpha\sin y}{\sin(\alpha+x)\sin(\alpha+\beta)}\cdot pq$$

Add them, and plug in $y=\pi-(\alpha+\beta+x)$

$$ac+bd=\frac{\sin x\sin\beta+\sin \alpha\sin(\alpha+\beta+x)}{\sin(\alpha+x)\sin(\alpha+\beta)}\cdot pq$$

Next, we need to show

$$\frac{\sin x\sin\beta+\sin \alpha\sin(\alpha+\beta+x)}{\sin(\alpha+x)\sin(\alpha+\beta)}=1$$

Start from the numerator,

$$\begin{align} 
\text{Numerator}&=\sin x\sin\beta+\sin \alpha\sin(\alpha+\beta+x)\\
\\
&=\sin x\sin\beta+\sin \alpha\sin(\alpha+\beta)\cos x+\sin\alpha\sin x\cos(\alpha+\beta)\\
\\
&=\sin x\sin\beta+\sin(\alpha+\beta)\cdot[\sin(\alpha+x)-\sin x\cos\alpha]+\sin\alpha\sin x\cos(\alpha+\beta)\\
\\
&=\sin x\sin\beta+\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha+x)-\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin x\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha\sin x\cos(\alpha+\beta)\\
\\
&=\sin x\sin\beta+\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha+x)-\sin x\cdot[\sin(\alpha+\beta)\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha\cos(\alpha+\beta)]\\
\\
&=\sin x\sin\beta+\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha+x)-\sin x\cdot[\sin(\beta)]\\
\\
&=\sin(\alpha+\beta)\sin(\alpha+x)\\
\\
&=\text{Denominator}\end{align}$$